# How to upload directory by curl in Linux command to FTP

Tags: linux, curl, command

I have this command:
curl -T /var/www/backups/file.sql.gz ftp://ftp.mydomain.com --user name@mydomain.com:pass

it is working successfully about uploading file, but I want same command to upload directory

Comment: You can't upload a whole directory in a single command. You have to iterate the directory uploading each file individually

Comment: OK, Thank you so much.